# Does an RDBMS delete its triggers when needed?

Tags: oracle, triggers

Suppose we have a trigger, named Foo.

Foo depends on the T table and depends on the a, b, c columns.

*If the T table is dropped, the T trigger is also dropped?*

*If c is deleted, is the T trigger dropped?*

*If an alteration happens for the T table, but it doesn't affect the a, b, c columns, is the T trigger dropped?*

Thank you in advance for your answers,

Best regards,
Lajos Arpad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only scenario where a trigger is dropped without an explicit

```
DROP TRIGGER <trigger_name>;
```

Is when the table is also dropped.

```
DROP <TABLE_NAME>;
```

In cases where the source code of the trigger references schema that is no longer present, the trigger becomes invalid.  You can query your database for invalid objects with:

```
   select * from user_objects where status != 'VALID'  
   -- invalid objects associated with the user you are logged in as
   select * from all_objects where status != 'VALID' 
   -- all invalid objects  in the database
```

There is a case where a drop 'cascades' when you specify a cascade.  But this is focused on dropping child tables.

```
drop table <table_name> cascade constraints;
```

Oracle 10g documentation on [DROP TABLE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/statements_9003.htm) DDL command.

All that said triggers are often misused and introduce bugs. I would encourage you to avoid placing your application logic in them.

Answer (score 3):

Having just tried, it, I can answer to your three questions:

1. If you drop the table *T* the trigger is also dropped.
2. If you drop a column that the trigger depends on (e.g. *c* in your example), the trigger is not dropped but instead it becomes invalid.  You then get an ORA-04098 'trigger XYZ is invalid and failed re-validation' error if the triggering event on the table happens (e.g. the trigger is a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger and you `INSERT` into the table).
3. If you make an alteration to the table *T* that does not affect the trigger, the trigger is not dropped and remains valid.

Answer (score 0):

You should really try this or consult Oracle docs/support. I don't have access to a Oracle DB right now (it's weekend ;-)) to verify it, but as far as I remember the results of these actions would be the following:

1. Yes (triggers are part of the respective table)
2. No effect on triggers
3. No effect on triggers